# Игра "Пятнашки"

Tags: c

С чего нужно начать реализацию этой игры? Если есть исходники, выложите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Экономьте свое время. Пользуйтесь [поиском][1].
[1]:https://www.google.ru/search?aq=0&oq=c+%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%BF&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c+%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8#hl=ru&newwindow=1&sa=X&ei=4VmYT-fGA-io4gSB26DFBg&sqi=2&ved=0CBoQvwUoAQ&q=c%2B%2B+%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=3fa92404c07a4654&biw=1366&bih=656

Comment: @julia, а вы случаем не в ВТУ учитесь? А то аналогичное задание получил от препода :)

Answer (score 1):

Начать надо с описания того, что нужно получить, далее идет конструирование общей архитектуры, потом разбивка на отдельные части (или модули),  потом составления алгоритмов отдельных узлов программы, а в конце - кодирование, выливающееся в тестирование и отладку.

Answer (score 0):

Начни с рандомного выкладывания пятнашек.  У меня есть догадки по алгоритму, но я не уверен, что это может быть так.